# Service Fabric: Should I split my API up into multiple little APIs?

Tags: asp.net, api, azure-service-fabric

I have been building .Net Web API's for years... normally I have one API that has 10 or so different controllers who handle everything from signing users up, handling business logic, payment, etc. Those all talk to class libraries to talk to the database and such. Nothing fancy, but it has been effective.

Fast forward to today... I am building a version 2 for an app  that gets a good amount of traffic. I know my app is gonna get hit hard so I am looking for something with a foundation of efficiency and scale.

This has led me to embrace the coolness of Service Fabric and ASP.Net Core Web APIs. I have been reading lots of tutorials, articles, and SO questions and from what I understand, the beauty of Service Fabric is that it will spawn up multiple nodes in a single VM when things get busy.

So, if I maintain my normal pattern and make a single Web API with 10+ controllers, can Service Fabric do what it needs to do? Or am I supposed to create multiple little API's that are more focused so that the Service Fabric can add/remove them as things get busy?

That sounds like the right thing to do, and I have set up my code to do just that by putting my Models and Data classes in their own class libraries so they can be reused by the different API's, but I just wanted to double check before I do something potentially stupid.

If I split up, say each controller into its own Service Fabric service, will the Azure server be more efficient and scale better?

Answer (score 2):

**Nodes**

In Service Fabric clusters (on Azure / stand alone) a Node equals a VM. If you increase the amount of machines, more Nodes appear in the cluster. (This is not the case for your local dev cluster.) Scaling in Azure Clusters is simple: just change the VMSS instance count.

Only if you configure Stateless Services with instance count -1, Service Fabric will spawn new instances of it. This is caused by the addition of nodes, not by load itself.
You can configure [autoscaling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-scale-up-down) for VMSS'es.

**Web API**

Service Fabric just tries to balance the load of all running SF Services across the available resources. That could be one instance of one service type on every node, or multiple instances of many types. So one service can just use all the resources of the node it's running on, like with IIS. (This is why Container support is coming by the way.)

Web API design isn't directly influenced by Service Fabric. The same rules apply as when running on IIS or elsewhere. It's really your choice.

**Microservices**

Your normal pattern will work. But making smaller services from it could help reduce the impact of changes. (At the cost of increased complexity.) Consider creating services that offer common functionality following the [Microservices](http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) paradigm.

In Microservices, your code changes are scoped to smaller modules, less testing is needed, performance is less degraded during updates. This way, in theory, you can release new features in less time.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If you have a natural division in your controllers regarding the resources they use then you may get some benefit if you split your services along that division line. Say service A uses lots of CPU and service B uses mostly HTTP then giving SF the ability to split CPU loads on their own may mean fewer affected HTTP calls.

You can optimize how SF distributes load by [reporting load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-metrics) from inside your app but do so in the simplest way possible and don't add numerous dimensions, maybe one per service at most.

If all your controllers use the same type of resources roughly the same then there's no real benefit to splitting them away in separate services, just complications in code management, deployments and potentially inter-service communications.